# Grouping large dataset of lakes into n clusters based on target total perimeter?

Tags: arcgis-desktop

There's a longer explanation of why I'm interested in this below, but in short, I'm wondering how to run something like a k nearest neighbors formula, with the number of groups determined by a maximum total characteristic(perimeter) in each group.

This is part of a cutesy project a friend and I are working on-

We're from Minnesota, often called the land of 10,000 lakes and are exploring what it'd look like to actually run around 10,000 lakes over a long period of time.

Finding the 10,000 largest was pretty trivial, as was generating perimeter measurements.

To start making "courses" to run, we're looking at dividing the lakes into groupings that are:

1) close together
and
2) about 8-15 miles in perimeter total between the lakes.

Any ideas on how to best accomplish this? I'm playing around with grouping analysis in ArcMap right now, but I'm pretty sure that there's a more optimal solution someone's made already.

Comment: There is Aggregate Polygons http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Aggregate_Polygons/00700000000s000000/ which will cluster polygons based on minimum distance but not so much to break these aggregations down into chunks, I would suggest iterative aggregations, removing clusters then manually splitting the chunks.. another approach is to get the centroids, create a Thiessen mesh and dissolve adjacent polygons until the required number is reached - not an easy task by any means.